# Gridview disappearing after post back when paging is enabled

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, datatable

My problem is that when I click the button to load the data into the gridview, it works fine. But when I click on a new page, the gridview disappears; I then have to click the button again to see it.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Here is the c#:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(strSQLConnection1);
SqlConnection sqlPopGrid = new SqlConnection(strSQLConnection1);
SqlCommand sqlCommandPopGrid = new SqlCommand("select id, quote, author from TABLE", sqlConnection1);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

sqlPopGrid.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommandPopGrid);
sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   grd1.DataSource = dt;
   grd1.DataBind();
}

sqlPopGrid.Close();
```

Here is the aspx:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
              AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" ID="grd1" 
              OnPageIndexChanging="grd1_PageIndexChanging" 
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="grd1_SelectedIndexChanged"  
              OnSorting="grd1_Sorting">
      <PagerSettings PageButtonCount="5"></PagerSettings>
</asp:GridView>
```

Btw I am using asp.net 4.0 if that is of any use.

Comment: Can you paste the code here for future reference who has the similar problem.

Comment: Ah i got it. Turns out i didnt have a pageChanged event, so when it changed it was not rebinding the data back :)